# Should I re-transform country dummy coefficients to be analyzed in a second stage?

Tags: data-transformation, econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, macroeconomics

I am working on panel (country-year) macroeconomic data which suffers from missing data in some of the independent variables. My sample is wide and short, around 120 countries over 10 years.

In past research on the same subject and using very similar data, I tried cross-country analysis on 10-year averages as well as multiple imputation analysis with a more restricted panel. From this research emerged what seemed to be a plausible story, i.e. the variables of structural nature (within time variation much smaller than cross-country) were more significant in the cross-country analysis and vice-versa.

Now I am starting a similar project with updated data and I would like to take into account the aforementioned salient fact by using a two-step procedure. In the first step, I used a LSDV estimator with country dummies and the short-term variables (which are the least affected by missing data), and in the second step, I would like to regress the coefficients of the country dummies on the 10-year-averaged values of (available) structural variables.

Because the OLS estimation with the raw data produced heteroskedasticity and a few very influential observations, I  log-transformed my dependent variable (which had a very skewed distribution) and one of the independent variables (the only one expressed in value) in the first step.

Before proceeding with the second stage of the analysis, I would like to know what are the pros and cons of re-exponentiating the coefficients of my country dummies versus using them as is, and what either choice entails for the specification of my cross-country "structural" model.